# How to make horizontal line seperate label and input?

Tags: css, input, grid, label, horizontal-line

I wanna make a field containing `label` and `input` separated by ***a Horizontal line dotted centered.***
like the description field:
[image]
What I've tried using *grid* with `span` (which is a horizontal line) and giving it `1fr` to take all space between `label` and `input`;
that's what I've tried so far:

```css
.field {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 40%;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
.field span {
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px dotted gray;
  border-top: 10px;
}
label {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
}
input {
  outline: 1px solid rgb(81, 81, 81);
  border: none;
  color: rgb(81, 81, 81);
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 3px;
}
input:focus {
  outline: 1.3px solid rgb(0, 131, 143);
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <label for="Description"> Description </label>
  <span></span><!--This is horizontal dotted line -->
  <input type="text" id="Description" />
</div>
```

but it seems not exactly the same as desired output in the image above, any suggestions of how to make the horizontal line much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I used flex-box with `align-items: center` instead of grid

```css
.field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  ...
}
```

And added a X-axis margin to the span

```css
.field span {
  margin: 0 16px;
  ...
}
```

You can also change the opacity of the span border color to make it closer to the image you attached

```css
.field span {
  border: 4px dotted rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.23);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, nice approach using `flex`; just a question could you guess about `font-family` used at the `label` in the image attached?

Comment: You can try uploading the image [here](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont) and the site you give you the fonts that this image could possibly be.